# Is this generator of large consecutive prime numbers unique?

Tags: prime-numbers

I've found no consecutive prime number generator on the internet that generates consecutive primes greater than about 17 digits.  This program will generate primes of up to 290 digits: https://jprime.netlify.app

And this YouTube video explains how to use the program:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6tHFiVhQMMM

So, are there other generators of consecutive prime numbers greater than 290 digits?

Comment: This really isn't a great place to publish results.

Comment: Is there some other place you can suggest that might be better?

Comment: You do not need a youtube video. Download the free and easy to use PARI/GP and just search random primes $p$ and the next prime $q$. Note that there is no known easy method to construct such prime pairs , they simply must be searched.

Comment: As @Peter suggested, I ran 68 primes your way (250 digit start).  Took 94sec on my laptop.  PariGP from same start did it in 7 sec.

Comment: I have no idea what the computer capacity is of the program that PARI/GP runs on.  The program is currently running on a free-to-use server.  A server with much higher capacity could make a big difference.  Furthermore, the program doesn't rely on starting with a random number.